# Creating subcommands with commons-cli

Tags: java, apache-commons-cli

I'm trying to create a simple argument parser using commons-cli and I can't seem to figure out how to create the following options:

```
java ... com.my.path.to.MyClass producer 
java ... com.my.path.to.MyClass consumer -j 8
```

The first argument to my program should be either `producer` or `consumer`, defining the mode which my program will run in. If it's in `consumer` mode, I'd like to have a `-j` argument which defines how many threads to service with.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
Options options = new Options();
options.addOption("mode", false, "Things.");

HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
formatter.printHelp("startup.sh", options);
```

When I print out these options, the `mode` parameter shows up as `-mode`.

In Python's `argparse`, I'd just do the following:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('mode', choices=('producer', 'consumer'), required=True)
parser.print_help()
```

This does exactly what I'm looking for. How can I do this in commons-cli?

Comment: my lazy approach would be to create a class for Producer and another to Consumer (sorry, I know this is not a real answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JCommander](http://jcommander.org) is the answer. commons-cli doesn't seem to support these options.

Answer (score 4):

What I've done for things like this is to have separate Options for each class. In your main, check the first argument to decide which list to pass to the parser. FWIW, I don't consider it "hack" solution.

Answer (score 2):

[picocli](https://github.com/remkop/picocli) is now included in Groovy 2.5.x.  It has built-in support for subcommands.

Comment: Just to be clear: picocli does not _require_ Groovy. You can use picocli to create command line apps with subcommands in Java. :-)